# Button_to not working as a link_to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I would be happy to know why this is not working. I'm trying to put a button instead a link on my navbar, the link is working but the button is not redirecting me to the page I want to.
this is the link which is working

```
      <%= link_to 'Iniciar Sesión', new_user_session_path, class: 'nav-link'%>
```

And this is the button link which is not redirecting me to the login page.

```
<%= button_to "Inciar Sesión", new_user_session_path, :method => "get", class: 'btn btn-outline-success' %>
```

Comment: What do you mean, not redirecting?

Comment: Well the button is not sending me to the login page and the link to is doing that when it has to do the same, it sticks on the page where I am at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link_to and button_to works in a different way.

Buttons aren't supposed to be sending GET requests.

You should use a link_to instead. If you want it to look like a button, apply some CSS. Here's a good article: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/18/designing-css-buttons-techniques-and-resources/

Comment: This was a huge help